# jquery missing { after property

Tags: jquery

I keep getting an error, missing { after property for the following code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var storage = new Array("hi","h2","hi3","h4","h5","6","7","hi8","hi9","10");
            // Slider
            $('#slider').slider({
                max: 10,
                orientation: 'vertical'
                slide: function(e,ui) {
                    $('#storage').html(storage[ui.value-1]);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a comma.

Replace:

```
orientation: 'vertical'
```

With

```
orientation: 'vertical',
```